# how to store each word form a text file (just once, no duplicates) in an ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I know  how to store each word form a text file in an Array List,but how can I  store each word only once? I mean no duplicates.
Thank you

```
public class Analyze
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        String l;
        Scanner f = new Scanner(
                new File("Readme.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> myArray=new ArrayList<String>();
        while(f.hasNext())
        {
            l=f.next();

            myArray.add(l);
            for(int i=0;i<myArray.size()-1;i++)
            if(l.equals(myArray.get(i)))
            myArray.remove(l);    
        }
         for(int i=0;i<myArray.size();i++)
        System.out.println(myArray.get(i));

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA: Preventing Duplicate Entries to an ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611751/java-preventing-duplicate-entries-to-an-arraylist)

Comment: Why a `List` and not just a `Set`? Also, do you have ordering constraints?

Comment: [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Comment: Does your "Readme.txt" only have one word at one line? If not you still need to split the read line at good points (spaces, punctuation marks).

Answer (score 2):

Either you can always do a lookup to your ArrayList (`ArrayList.contains()`) if the word you're about to add is already contained in it. Or you could use a Set to read your Textfile into and then later use this Set to initialize your ArrayList (`new ArrayList<String>(mySetOfUniqueWords);`). This however heavily depends on whether the order of occurrence of the words is important to you or not.

This however does not work if your words occur in different case ("test","Test","TeSt" will be handled like different words from both approaches). If you want to collect those words into one instance you could simply implement your own wrapper that overrides the `equals` Method for Strings or your own WordSet/WordList implementation that overrides the neccessary methods to fulfil this requirement (`contains(), add(), addAll()`).

Comment: ArrayList lookup is `O(n)` . For a Set, its `O(1)` (almost :P). Better to use a Set

Answer (score 1):

you have the following options:

- use a `Set` (see the other answers)
- check if the list already contains the entry (also described by others)
- create a unique list after creating the one with possible duplicates like this: `List<String> unique = originalList.stream().unique().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 0):

Use [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method to find it the list have that element

Or store the data in [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) it doesn't allow duplicates

```
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
str.add("This");
str.add("is");
str.add("a");
str.add("Test");
str.add("This");
str.add("a");
str.add("is");

 for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++) {
     if(!temp.contains(str.get(i))){
         temp.add(str.get(i));
      }
 }
```

Working [Example](https://ideone.com/XgBk8W)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use a structure which handles the deduplication for you, like a Set, and then copy the contents of that into an ArrayList:

```
Set<String> strings = new LinkedHashSet<>();  // preserves insertion order.
while (f.hasNext()) {
  strings.add(f.next());
}
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(strings);
```