# How to prevent duplicate user entries into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

The point is to basically ask for the user to input a name. Then, another. And to store it in an array. Then, if the user enters a duplicate name, it should print a line saying, please enter another name.
Here is my code(so far...also please point out any syntax errors..much appreciated...also no hashsets or linkedhashsets because we haven't covered that in class yet):

```
import java.util.Scanner
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.Arraylist

class noduplicates 
{

    static final int max = 5;
public static void main(String[] args);


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int     num = 0;
float   total = 0;
float[] Array = new float [max];
String[] name = new String [max];


    // Read and store all marks, (only store)
while (num < max)
{

    System.out.println("Enter name");
    name[num] = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a name");
    name[num] = input.nextLine();
    arryList.contains("name");
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to use arrays? You could use other solutions that may be easier to work with, like ArrayList.

Comment: Yes, I realized. I decided to try to use ArrayList

Comment: good luck. This question was closed before I could post a code example - I hope the other questions mentioned in the title will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either loop through the array before adding any name, or use `ArrayList` and check if name already exists using the method `arrayList.contains("name");`.

Also you may use `LinkedHashSet` as in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20611826/5137352).

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to `List`, `Array` doesn't have a `contains()` method.

Either iterate values of the array to check if one of them `equals()` the new input or use `Arrays.asList(array ).contains(input)`.
The last one is much less efficient but for a short list, it is not a problem.

Using a `Set` is also an option.
It will not spare you checking if the element is duplicated as you need to print a message to the user in this case but it will make the code more robust by guaranteeing that the collection never contains duplicate `String`s.

Comment: A Set will spare you checking if the element is a duplicate: `add` returns false if an attempt is made to add an existing entry.

Comment: @Modus Tollens You are right but using the return value of `add()` is a check to know it the element is duplicated.

Comment: You are right, but you don't have to add another line or check it yourself. if (!add(...) print("name exists") would suffice.

Comment: It is a little more short indeed but it stays a check.

Comment: this is for a class. and we haven't covered hashsets and all yet.

Comment: @TechnoSavage Please add this requirement to your question.

Comment: @Modus Tollens I did