# How to avoid addition of same item to the arraylist?

Tags: java, android, jsoup, barcode-scanner

There is a POJO called Product in my project which contains fields like productName(String), costPrice(int), sellingPrice(int).

I'm scanning a barcode and putting the resultant number into the productName field of the Product.

```java
Product product = new Product(UPC, 20,10);
```

Now, I'm putting this 'Product' POJO in an arraylist. I don't want products with same productName(i.e. same barcode number) to be added again and again.

```java
if (arraylist.contains(product)) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Product already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    arraylist.add(product);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But, since contains() method only checks if the same Product object exists in it and not the same UPC(barcode number), so it adds the Products with same UPC(barcode) number again and again.

Please tell me a way to check for the 'productName' field of the Product object so that duplicate productName (i.e. UPC/barcode number) can be avoided.

Comment: Welcome to [so] - Please take the [tour] and review our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  For starters, please reduce your code into a [mre] for faster troubleshooting

Comment: If the problem still persists... you could try write your own contains method comparing the object you want to save with the one you already have in the array.

Comment: From your vague description, maybe you want a `Set` instead an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20611751/642706)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA: Preventing Duplicate Entries to an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611751/java-preventing-duplicate-entries-to-an-arraylist)

Comment: Override method `equals` in class `Product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean isContains = false;
String productName = product.getProductName();

for (Product productItem : arraylist) {
    if (productItem.getProductName().equals(productName)) {
        isContains = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (isContains) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Product already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    arraylist.add(product);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Add productName in arraylist after full comparison